# How to vectorize calling functions in a cell array?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, func

I have a matrix

```
x = rand(10,100,3);
```

and a function cell array: pseudo code is

```
funcca = {...
    @(v)(v(1)+v(2)), @(v)(v(1)-v(2)), ......,   @(v)(v(1)+v(2)+v(3)^2);
    ⋮
    ⋮
    @(v)(v(1)^6+sqrt(v(3))), @(v)(sin(v(1))-cos(v(2))),......,@(v)(v(1))
};
```

where `size(funcca) = [10, 100]`. It means that each function in `funcca` is different!

Now I use the following code to calculate `y`:

```
y = nan(10,100);
for i = 1 :10
    for j = 1:100 
        y(i,j) = funcca{i,j}(squeeze(x(i,j,:)));
    end
end
```

Is there a way where I could avoid this two `for` loops or vectorize this process?

Comment: Loosely speaking vectorization is about converting multiple call of a function for each element of a array input to single call of it for the whole array. but here the problem is calling 1000 different functions instead of for loop , so there is no place for vectorization.

Comment: your function must be vectorized not the way you call it.

Comment: I think your main performance problem is the `squeeze` inside the loop; that is not a MATLAB built-in, meaning, JIT can't compile it and you'll get terrible performance. Just do a `permute` before the loop and adjust the extraction indices inside the loop, that should improve things rather significantly.

Comment: Any particular reason `funcca` is a "cell of anonymous functions" instead of a proper function doing the calculations inside? If the only answer is that the anonymous functions are passed at runtime, you can make such a function accept variable arguments with `varargin`. Your end call might look something like `applyfuncs(myvar, n_output_rows, n_output_cols, func1, func2, func3, ...)`

Comment: As for "can I vectorise this", probably not. If you have 1000 functions that need to be called at some point or another, then they need to be called at some point or another, and there's no "vectorising" optimisation that will call them more efficiently. You can, however, attempt to parallelise this with `parfor`, since the output of each iteration is independent.

Answer (score 0):

The matlab function `cellfun` will let you perform an operation over every element in a cell array. In this case:

```
y = cellfun(@(c)c(rand(1, 3)), funcca);
```

or if `x` should actually be explicit data and not randomly generated as in your question, then something like

```
y = cellfun(@(fh, data)fh(squeeze(data)), funcca, num2cell(x, 3));
```

Comment: Actually cellfun does not vectorize the operation, this is just "an hidden for loop"

Comment: But it's no longer your fault. Now it's MathWorks fault for not vectorizing cellfun

Comment: no need to `squeeze`; by the looks of it, `funcca` explicitly calls elements `1`, `2` and `3`, which you can do just as well in a 1×1×3 array.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki ...and how exactly does that help the OP?

Comment: He can have a clean consciousness knowing that it's not his fault but MathWorks, so he can sleep better at night.

Comment: It helps the OP because 1) it is a cleaner expression of what the OP wants to do, therefore easier to understand and maintain; and 2) it explicitly indicates independence between the evaluations of the elements of `funcca`, which in theory permits `matlab` to perform operations as efficiently as it can, e.g. if they were to introduce parallelisation of `cellfun`.

Comment: `cellfun` no more explicitly indicates independence between evaluations of elements than the explicit `for` loop does

Comment: @excaza: That's not true. A `for` loop can very easily have dependence between loop iterations. A `cellfun` call explicitly cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the call to `cellfun` should look like this:

```
z = cellfun(@(f,y) f(y), funcca, num2cell(x,3));
```

But, as indicated by obchardon, this may not actually give you a speed up. It just saves you some typing.

Actually, I think it's more a design problem -- How did you end up with that array of functions? Can you provide some context?